# Google map pin doesnt show at first time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am using following code to show the pin of current location in Google map.But when i click the button to show the pin,1st time pin doesnt show but when i click it second time it ll show the pin.
Please suggest me the alternate:

```
     UIButton *myDetailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    //UIButton *myDetailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton];
    myDetailButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 23, 23);
    myDetailButton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    myDetailButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
    myDetailButton.tag = tag;
    tag++;
    //[myDetailButton addTarget:self action:@selector(gotoBusinessDetail:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // Set the button as the callout view
    currentMarkerAnnotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = myDetailButton;


    currentMarkerAnnotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"redmarker.png"];
    currentMarkerAnnotationView.canShowCallout = NO;        

    return currentMarkerAnnotationView;
```

Comment: can you post the complete code.

Comment: source code please....also you are saying when i press the button the pin is not visible and you have commented the code                 [myDetailButton addTarget:self action:@selector(gotoBusinessDetail:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];